# Apache Camel - How to make a value accessible across the entire route?

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I am trying out a Camel route that queries a table (with primary key), generates a CSV based on the query response and stores the CSV file in Azure storage container. After successfully storing the file in Azure, I need to update a flag in the table that was queried initially. For this purpose I am setting the primary key as part of the header, but after the azure endpoint is executed, the header values are getting reset. So I am not able to retrieve the initial header and hence the primary key value which I need. What is the ideal way to store a value that is accessible during the entire route?

```
from("direct:processPayroll")
  .setHeader("payrollId",simple("${body.payrollId}"))
  .to("sql:classpath:sql/payroll.sql")
  .marshal(csvFormat)
  .log("${headers}")
  .to("azure-storage-blob://staccount/container?blobName=payroll.csv&operation=uploadBlockBlob")
  .log("${headers}")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store it in the exchange properties. You can add the value using `.setProperty("key","value")` and retrieve it using `$exchangeProperty("key")`